# Reading stock data from Yahoo using Python 3.4 and not able remove the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, yahoo-finance

I'm using Python 3.4 and I'm trying to download the data from Yahoo finance.
Below is my code:

```
import urllib.request  
url = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=aapl&a=6&b=21&c=2014&d=6&e=29&f=2014'  
csv = urllib.request.urlopen(url).readlines()  
print(csv)  
ds,open_,high,low,close,volume,adjc = csv[1].strip().split('\n')
```

Result:

```
[b'Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close\n', b'2014-07-29,99.33,99.44,98.25,98.38,43031400,98.38\n', b'2014-07-28,97.82,99.24,97.55,99.02,55239000,99.02\n', b'2014-07-25,96.85,97.84,96.64,97.67,43403200,97.67\n', b'2014-07-24,97.04,97.32,96.42,97.03,45663100,97.03\n', b'2014-07-23,95.42,97.88,95.17,97.19,92844700,97.19\n', b'2014-07-22,94.68,94.89,94.12,94.72,54914800,94.72\n', b'2014-07-21,94.99,95.00,93.72,93.94,38887700,93.94\n']  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>  
    ds,open_,high,low,close,volume,adjc = csv[1].strip().split('\n')  
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

Now the problem I'm facing is when I'm trying to split the csv and store the individual line as a separate value. 
So I want to split and store the quote. But I'm not able to do it because there is character 'b' in front and '\n' in the end. Can you guys help me to split or suggest an alternative writing solution?

I really appreciate your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1) I find the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library much easier to use than `urllib.request`.

2) If the data is in CSV format, I recommend the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module instead of parsing the file yourself.

Here is how I would do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
import csv
import pprint

url='http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=aapl&a=6&b=21&c=2014&d=6&e=29&f=2014'

http_response=requests.get(url)
stock_reader=csv.reader(http_response.text.splitlines())
stock_data=list(stock_reader)
pprint.pprint(stock_data)

ds,open_,high,low,close,volume,adjc = stock_data[1]
print("The stock opened at {} on {}".format(open_,ds))
print("The average closing price was {0:.02f}".format(
    sum(float(item[4]) for item in stock_data[1:])/len(stock_data[1:])))
```

For added convenience, try [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```
http_response=requests.get(url)
stock_reader=csv.DictReader(http_response.text.splitlines())
stock_data=list(stock_reader)

print("The stock opened at {Open} on {Date}".format(**stock_data[0]))
print("The average closing price was {0:.02f}".format(
    sum(float(item['Close']) for item in stock_data)/len(stock_data)))
```